# Bootstrap and css are not being recognized in my plugin

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am trying to make my own plugin on Wordpress but the bootstrap and css don't work,  there is no connection being formed between them. Here is my code, if you have any idea about that I will be very thankful.

```
 function my_options_style() {
      wp_register_style('my_options_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/style.css', false, '1.0.0');
      wp_register_style('bootstrap_options_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'includes/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, '1.0.0');
      wp_register_style('bootstrap_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'includes/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', false, '1.0.0');
      wp_enqueue_style('my_options_css');
      wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_options_css');
      wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css');
     }
     add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_options_style');

     function theme_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ads', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'includes/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.1', true );
     }
     add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like this  wp_register_style()  & wp_register_script()

Demo **for Registers Script**

```
// Register Script
function custom_scripts() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js', false, '2.1.1', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrap' );
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.2.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

And For **Register Style**

```
// Register Style
function custom_styles() {

    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, '3.2.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );

    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-theme', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', array( 'bootstrap' ), '3.2.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-theme' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_styles' );
```

*For more details*

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/